# javascript replace multiple div tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As I'm currently working on a calendar system with some product integration, I want to make it possible to see if there is a product attached to the event in the calendar.

Currently I have this function that opens a file and sends an ID to get the product name, but the problem is that if there is multiple `<div id="productX"></div>` (Replace x with the product id) on the page, then it only replace the first div tag it finds.

```
function getProductname(id){
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://XX.com/api/calendar_getname.php',
    data: 'id=' + id,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#product' + id).html(data);
    }
});
```

};

Is there somehow I can make it replace multiple of the same div tags around the page?
Like if it finds `<div id="product0">X</div>` 2 items it replace it X with the value it get's from the page.

Hope it's understandable at some points.

Comment: IDs are unique. What you should use is class.

Comment: Its called `getElementById` for a reason. Otherwise it would have been called `getElementsById`.

Comment: Still a bit new to this, but at least I learned something new today!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID is unique to one element, you should use a class instead and then target that

`<div class="productX"></div>`

Comment: @Nature Good to hear :) also if this helped you out ticket this as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
$('#product' + id).html(data);
```

by this:

```
$('[id="product"'+id+']').html(data);
```

[Here is a **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2gqrawcn/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you have the divs like

```
<div class='product'></div>
```

But if you insist to use Id, there's still way to achieve by using

[Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```js
$('#b1').click(function() {
  $('div.product').html('By Class');
});

$('#b2').click(function() {  
  // Get all div which id starts with product.
  $('div[id^="product"]').html('By ID');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="product1" class="product"></div>
<div id="product2" class="product"></div>
<div id="product3" class="product"></div>
<div id="product4" class="product"></div>
<button id="b1">By Class</button>
<button id="b2">By ID</button>
```